# Array Remove last 2 digits of a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, slice, digit

I would like to create a program that takes a number is input, such as: 12345 and then splits this number into 2 digit numbers and store it in a array. The array must look like this: [0]=45 [1]=23 [2]=1 . This means that the splitting of the numbers must start from the last digit of the number and not the first.

This is what I have until now:

```js
var splitCount = []; // This is the array in which we store our split numbers
//Getting api results via jQuery's GET request
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCJwchuXd_UWNxW-Z1Cg-liw&key=AIzaSyDUzfsMaYjn7dnGXy9ZEtQB_CuHyii4poc", function(result) {
    //result is our api answer and contains the recieved data
    //now we put the subscriber count into another variable (count); this is just for clarity
    count = result.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
    //While the subscriber count still has characters
    while (count.length) {
        splitCount.push(count.substr(0, 2)); //Push first two characters into the splitCount array from line 1
        count = count.substr(2); //Remove first two characters from the count string
    }       
    console.log(splitCount) //Output our splitCount array
});
```

but the problem with this is that if there are 5 digits for example: 12345 the the last digit will be in an array by itself like this: [0]=12 [1]=34 [2]=5 but I need the last array to have 2 digits and the first should be the one with one digit instead like this: [0]=1 [1]=23 [2]=45

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code to show us what you've already done?

Comment: Are we assuming the input is always integers?

Comment: Yes I have this code (added above)

Answer (score 0):

very crude but this should work assuming the string is always numbers:

```
input = "12345"

def chop_it_up(input)
  o = []

  while input.length > 0
    if input.length <= 2
      o << input
    else
      o << input[-2..input.length]
    end
    input = input[0..-3]
    chop_it_up(input)
  end

  return o
end
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I needed it in JS

Comment: It wouldn't be that hard to convert what I've written in Ruby to JS... give it a shot.

Comment: it probably isnt but I am very new to coding, only 15 and I have no clue about Ruby and currently trying to learn JS. I would be really thankful if you could help me with that

Comment: you should've tagged the question as javascript in that case; sorry. I'm sure someone whos good at JS will be willing to help :)

Comment: it is tagged with Javascript

Comment: Originally it wasn't :)

Answer (score 0):

I probably do sth like this :

```
int[] fun(int x){
   int xtmp = x;
   int i = 0;
   int len = String.valueOf(x).length(); 
   // this is a function for java, but you can probably find 
   //an equivalent in whatever language you use
   int tab[(len+1)/2];
   while(xtmp > 1){
       tab[i] = xtmp%100;
       xtmp = int(xtmp/100); // here you take the integer part of your xtmp
       ++i;
   }
   return tab;
}
```